# Branch io not updated without install the app iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, branch.io

In our project, we are using pod branch version 0.34.0 and we are following the below steps for installing the app. We are facing issue in the point2.

1.When the app is installed and clicked the deep link, it redirected to app and we are able to retrieve the deep link data’s from the branch. So the the values are updated and able to continue using the app.

2.When we click the Deep link without installing the app, it redirected to app store and we are not able to retrieve the deep link data’s from the branch. So the values are not updated and not able to continue using the app.

Xcode version: 11.5

This is the code we are using in our project:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController: true, deepLinkHandler: { params, error in
if error == nil {
//extract the value
}else {
//error
}


 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        Branch.getInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
return true
    }


func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)
return true
    }
```

We have followed the branch integration in dashboard. Do we need to modify any other changes in our project? This is the below response while app link not working.

**Optional([AnyHashable("+is_first_session"): 0, AnyHashable("+clicked_branch_link"): 0])**

Comment: Since you are unable to get deep link data when your fresh install the app, could you share the Branch SDK response in such a case? Also, can you share the link with which you are testing this?

Comment: Updated the SDK response @KartikShandilya